# Locating file controlling instance maxplayers

Tags: mysql, world-of-warcraft, azerothcore

I've been trying to find the file in the azerothcore SQL database that controls instance max players, but I seem to be unable to locate it. My goal is changing the maximum amount of players allowed in a 5man dungeon to 10man, but MapDifficulty.dbc and Map.dbc appear to not have any specific data, but rather redirect to other files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Other emulators [offer this value](https://github.com/cmangos/issues/wiki/Instance_template) in the database `instance_template` table. This table in AC lacks the `maxPlayers` value. I've also checked in the `dungeon_access_template` which seems like another relevant table, but that only lists level requirements and gear score requirements.

I've browsed through some of the source code, and I can't seem to find where this value is coming from either.

I've created [an issue on the AzerothCore Github](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/issues/5105) to address this problem.